# CAB does not shows up in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-layout

I have added the code for Cab on an already existing RecyclerView, in Android studio it does not shows any error, while in the emulator OnLongClick nothing happens. Any help is appreciated.
It seems like it code does nothing.

```
public class LoaderActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<List<Music>> {

private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private MusicAdapter musicAdapter;

ActionMode actionMode;
public static final String TAG = "YOUR-TAG-NAME";
/**
 * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
 * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
 */
private GoogleApiClient client;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    onContentChanged();
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_loader);

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerVw);
    // Use a LinearLayoutManager to make the RecyclerView display the Music in a vertically scrolling list.
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    musicAdapter = new MusicAdapter(this, new ArrayList<Music>());
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(musicAdapter);

    mRecyclerView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            if (actionMode!=null){
                return true;
            }
            else {
                actionMode=LoaderActivity.this.startActionMode(callback);
                return true;
            }

        }
    });
    final LoaderManager supportLoaderManager = getSupportLoaderManager();
    supportLoaderManager.initLoader(1, null, this);
    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
}
private ActionMode.Callback callback=new ActionMode.Callback() {
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu)
    {
        MenuInflater menuInflater=getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main,menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        mode.setTitle("1 item is selected");
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId()==R.id.id_delete)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"you really want to delete?",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }
        else
        if (item.getItemId()==R.id.id_share) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "you really want to share?", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {



    }

    };
```

Music Adapter

```
 public MusicAdapter(Context context, List<Music> music) {
        mMusic = new ArrayList<>();
        if(music != null) {
            mMusic.addAll(music);
        }
        mContext = context;
        mPlaceholder = (BitmapDrawable) mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_music_note_black_48dp);
        // Get the maximum size of byte we are allowed to allocate on the VM head and convert it to bytes.
        int maxSize = (int) (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024);
        // Divide the maximum size by eight to get a adequate size the LRU cache should reach before it starts to evict bitmaps.
        int cacheSize = maxSize / 8;
        mBitmapCache = new LruCache<Long, Bitmap>(cacheSize) {

            @Override
            protected int sizeOf(Long key, Bitmap value) {
                // returns the size of bitmaps in kilobytes.
                return value.getByteCount() / 1024;
            }
        };
    }
    /**
     * Adds a {@link Music} item to the Adapter.
     * @param
     */
    /**
     * Adds a {@link List} of {@link Music} to the adapters.
     * This method replaces the current music items inside of the adapter with the specified music items.
     * @param
     */
    public void clearItem() {
        mMusic.clear();
    }
    public void addItems(List<Music> music) {
        // Clear the old items. I only do this so that I don't have to do duplicating checks on the music items.
        mMusic.clear();
        // Add the new music list.
        mMusic.addAll(music);
        notifyItemRangeInserted(0, music.size());
    }
    /**
     * Clears the {@link Music} items inside of this adapter.
     */
    @Override
    public MusicViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        MusicViewHolder musicViewHolder = new MusicViewHolder(v);
        return musicViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MusicViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final Music music = mMusic.get(position);
        holder.itemView.setLongClickable(true);
        // Check the Bitmap cache for the album art first..
        final Bitmap bitmap = mBitmapCache.get(music.getAlbumId());
        // If the bitmap is not null, then use the cached images.
        if(bitmap != null){
            holder.icon.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
        else {
            // No album art could be found in the cache try reloading it.
            // In a real work example you should check that this value is not some junk value indicating that their is no album artwork.
            loadAlbumArt(holder.icon, music.getAlbumId());
        }

        holder.artist.setText(music.getArtist());
        holder.title.setText(music.getTitle());
        final Uri trackuri= ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, music.getId());
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onClick(View v) {

                                                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, Playrecord.class);
                                                intent.setData(trackuri);
                                                mContext.startActivity(intent);


                                            }
                                            });





    }



    /**
     * Helper method for asynchronously loading album art.
     * @param icon
     * @param albumId
     */
    public void loadAlbumArt(ImageView icon, long albumId) {
        // Check the current album art task if any and cancel it, if it is loading album art that doesn't match the specified album id.
        if(cancelLoadTask(icon, albumId)) {
             // There was either no task running or it was loading a different image so create a new one to load the proper image.
            LoadAlbumArt loadAlbumArt = new LoadAlbumArt(icon, mContext);
            // Store the task inside of the async drawable.
            AsyncDrawable drawable = new AsyncDrawable(mContext.getResources(), mPlaceholder.getBitmap(),loadAlbumArt);
            icon.setImageDrawable(drawable);
            loadAlbumArt.execute(albumId);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Helper method cancelling {@link LoadAlbumArt}.
     *
     * @param icon
     * @param albumId
     * @return
     */
    public boolean cancelLoadTask(ImageView icon, long albumId) {
        LoadAlbumArt loadAlbumArt = (LoadAlbumArt) getLoadTask(icon);
        // If the task is null return true because we want to try and load the album art.
        if(loadAlbumArt == null) {
            return true;
        }
        if(loadAlbumArt != null) {
            // If the album id differs cancel this task because it cannot be recycled for this imageview.
            if(loadAlbumArt.albumId != albumId) {
                loadAlbumArt.cancel(true);
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Helper method for extracting an {@link LoadAlbumArt}.
     * @param icon
     * @return
     */
    public AsyncTask getLoadTask(ImageView icon) {
        LoadAlbumArt task = null;
        Drawable drawable = icon.getDrawable();
        if(drawable instanceof AsyncDrawable) {
            task = ((AsyncDrawable) drawable).getLoadArtworkTask();
        }
        return task;
    }

    public void remove(long itemId) {
    }


    private class LoadAlbumArt extends AsyncTask<Long, Void, Bitmap> {

        // URI that points to the AlbumArt database.
        private final Uri albumArtURI = Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart");
        public WeakReference<ImageView> mIcon;
        // Holds a publicly accessible albumId to be checked against.
        public long albumId;
        public Context mContext;
        int width, height;

        public LoadAlbumArt(ImageView icon, Context context) {
            // Store a weak reference to the imageView.
            mIcon = new WeakReference<ImageView>(icon);
            // Store the width and height of the imageview.
            // This is necessary for properly scalling the bitmap.
            width = icon.getWidth();
            height = icon.getHeight();
            mContext = context;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
            if(isCancelled() || bitmap == null){
                return;
            }
            // Check to make sure that the imageview has not been garbage collected as well as the
            // LoadArtworkTask is the same as this one.
            if(mIcon != null && mIcon.get() != null) {
                ImageView icon = mIcon.get();
                Drawable drawable = icon.getDrawable();
                if(drawable instanceof AsyncDrawable) {
                    LoadAlbumArt task = ((AsyncDrawable) drawable).getLoadArtworkTask();
                    // Make sure that this is the same task as the one current stored inside of the ImageView's drawable.
                    if(task != null && task == this) {
                        icon.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    }
                }
            }
            mBitmapCache.put(albumId, bitmap);
            super.onPostExecute(bitmap);
        }

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(Long... params) {
            // AsyncTask are not guaranteed to start immediately and could be cancelled somewhere in between calling doInBackground.
            if(isCancelled()){
                return null;
            }
            albumId = params[0];
            // Append the albumId to the end of the albumArtURI to create a new Uri that should point directly to the album art if it exist.
            Uri albumArt = ContentUris.withAppendedId(albumArtURI, albumId);
            Bitmap bmp = null;

            return bmp;
        }
    }
    /**
     * Custom drawable that holds a LoadArtworkTask
     */

    private static class AsyncDrawable extends BitmapDrawable {
        WeakReference<LoadAlbumArt> loadArtworkTaskWeakReference;

        public AsyncDrawable(Resources resources, Bitmap bitmap, LoadAlbumArt task) {
            super(resources, bitmap);
            // Store the LoadArtwork task inside of a weak reference so it can still be garbage collected.
            loadArtworkTaskWeakReference = new WeakReference<LoadAlbumArt>(task);
        }

        public LoadAlbumArt getLoadArtworkTask() {
            return loadArtworkTaskWeakReference.get();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mMusic.size();
    }

    /**
     * Custom ViewHolder that represents the List Item.
     */
    public static class MusicViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder  {

        ImageView icon;
        TextView title;
        TextView artist;

        public MusicViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            icon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            artist = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.subtitle);
        }



 }
```

Comment: Post MusicAdapter code

Comment: added the code @JuanHurtado

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for uploading the adapter, the issue is that you are setting the recycler view itself on long item click listener and not the views on the adapter, what you have to do is to create an interface on the adapter to listen to long clicks just like you did with the the intent triggered on click i added the interface to your adapter :

```
public class MusicAdaper {

    public interface onLongItemClickLLsitener {
        void onLonClick(View view);
    }

    private onLongItemClickLLsitener mCallback;

    public MusicAdapter(Context context, List<Music> music, onLongItemClickLLsitener listener) {

        mCallback = listener;
        mMusic = new ArrayList<>();
        if(music != null) {
            mMusic.addAll(music);
        }
        mContext = context;
        mPlaceholder = (BitmapDrawable) mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_music_note_black_48dp);
        // Get the maximum size of byte we are allowed to allocate on the VM head and convert it to bytes.
        int maxSize = (int) (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024);
        // Divide the maximum size by eight to get a adequate size the LRU cache should reach before it starts to evict bitmaps.
        int cacheSize = maxSize / 8;
        mBitmapCache = new LruCache<Long, Bitmap>(cacheSize) {

            @Override
            protected int sizeOf(Long key, Bitmap value) {
                // returns the size of bitmaps in kilobytes.
                return value.getByteCount() / 1024;
            }
        };
    }
    /**
     * Adds a {@link Music} item to the Adapter.
     * @param
     */
    /**
     * Adds a {@link List} of {@link Music} to the adapters.
     * This method replaces the current music items inside of the adapter with the specified music items.
     * @param
     */
    public void clearItem() {
        mMusic.clear();
    }
    public void addItems(List<Music> music) {
        // Clear the old items. I only do this so that I don't have to do duplicating checks on the music items.
        mMusic.clear();
        // Add the new music list.
        mMusic.addAll(music);
        notifyItemRangeInserted(0, music.size());
    }
    /**
     * Clears the {@link Music} items inside of this adapter.
     */
    @Override
    public MusicViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        MusicViewHolder musicViewHolder = new MusicViewHolder(v);
        return musicViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MusicViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final Music music = mMusic.get(position);
        holder.itemView.setLongClickable(true);
        // Check the Bitmap cache for the album art first..
        final Bitmap bitmap = mBitmapCache.get(music.getAlbumId());
        // If the bitmap is not null, then use the cached images.
        if(bitmap != null){
            holder.icon.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
        else {
            // No album art could be found in the cache try reloading it.
            // In a real work example you should check that this value is not some junk value indicating that their is no album artwork.
            loadAlbumArt(holder.icon, music.getAlbumId());
        }

        holder.artist.setText(music.getArtist());
        holder.title.setText(music.getTitle());
        final Uri trackuri= ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, music.getId());

        holder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                mCallback.onLonClick(v);
                return false;
            }
        });

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, Playrecord.class);
                intent.setData(trackuri);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);


            }
        });





    }



    /**
     * Helper method for asynchronously loading album art.
     * @param icon
     * @param albumId
     */
    public void loadAlbumArt(ImageView icon, long albumId) {
        // Check the current album art task if any and cancel it, if it is loading album art that doesn't match the specified album id.
        if(cancelLoadTask(icon, albumId)) {
            // There was either no task running or it was loading a different image so create a new one to load the proper image.
            LoadAlbumArt loadAlbumArt = new LoadAlbumArt(icon, mContext);
            // Store the task inside of the async drawable.
            AsyncDrawable drawable = new AsyncDrawable(mContext.getResources(), mPlaceholder.getBitmap(),loadAlbumArt);
            icon.setImageDrawable(drawable);
            loadAlbumArt.execute(albumId);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Helper method cancelling {@link LoadAlbumArt}.
     *
     * @param icon
     * @param albumId
     * @return
     */
    public boolean cancelLoadTask(ImageView icon, long albumId) {
        LoadAlbumArt loadAlbumArt = (LoadAlbumArt) getLoadTask(icon);
        // If the task is null return true because we want to try and load the album art.
        if(loadAlbumArt == null) {
            return true;
        }
        if(loadAlbumArt != null) {
            // If the album id differs cancel this task because it cannot be recycled for this imageview.
            if(loadAlbumArt.albumId != albumId) {
                loadAlbumArt.cancel(true);
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Helper method for extracting an {@link LoadAlbumArt}.
     * @param icon
     * @return
     */
    public AsyncTask getLoadTask(ImageView icon) {
        LoadAlbumArt task = null;
        Drawable drawable = icon.getDrawable();
        if(drawable instanceof AsyncDrawable) {
            task = ((AsyncDrawable) drawable).getLoadArtworkTask();
        }
        return task;
    }

    public void remove(long itemId) {
    }


    private class LoadAlbumArt extends AsyncTask<Long, Void, Bitmap> {

        // URI that points to the AlbumArt database.
        private final Uri albumArtURI = Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart");
        public WeakReference<ImageView> mIcon;
        // Holds a publicly accessible albumId to be checked against.
        public long albumId;
        public Context mContext;
        int width, height;

        public LoadAlbumArt(ImageView icon, Context context) {
            // Store a weak reference to the imageView.
            mIcon = new WeakReference<ImageView>(icon);
            // Store the width and height of the imageview.
            // This is necessary for properly scalling the bitmap.
            width = icon.getWidth();
            height = icon.getHeight();
            mContext = context;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
            if(isCancelled() || bitmap == null){
                return;
            }
            // Check to make sure that the imageview has not been garbage collected as well as the
            // LoadArtworkTask is the same as this one.
            if(mIcon != null && mIcon.get() != null) {
                ImageView icon = mIcon.get();
                Drawable drawable = icon.getDrawable();
                if(drawable instanceof AsyncDrawable) {
                    LoadAlbumArt task = ((AsyncDrawable) drawable).getLoadArtworkTask();
                    // Make sure that this is the same task as the one current stored inside of the ImageView's drawable.
                    if(task != null && task == this) {
                        icon.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    }
                }
            }
            mBitmapCache.put(albumId, bitmap);
            super.onPostExecute(bitmap);
        }

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(Long... params) {
            // AsyncTask are not guaranteed to start immediately and could be cancelled somewhere in between calling doInBackground.
            if(isCancelled()){
                return null;
            }
            albumId = params[0];
            // Append the albumId to the end of the albumArtURI to create a new Uri that should point directly to the album art if it exist.
            Uri albumArt = ContentUris.withAppendedId(albumArtURI, albumId);
            Bitmap bmp = null;

            return bmp;
        }
    }
    /**
     * Custom drawable that holds a LoadArtworkTask
     */

    private static class AsyncDrawable extends BitmapDrawable {
        WeakReference<LoadAlbumArt> loadArtworkTaskWeakReference;

        public AsyncDrawable(Resources resources, Bitmap bitmap, LoadAlbumArt task) {
            super(resources, bitmap);
            // Store the LoadArtwork task inside of a weak reference so it can still be garbage collected.
            loadArtworkTaskWeakReference = new WeakReference<LoadAlbumArt>(task);
        }

        public LoadAlbumArt getLoadArtworkTask() {
            return loadArtworkTaskWeakReference.get();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mMusic.size();
    }

    /**
     * Custom ViewHolder that represents the List Item.
     */
    public static class MusicViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder  {

        ImageView icon;
        TextView title;
        TextView artist;

        public MusicViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            icon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            artist = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.subtitle);
        }



    }
}
```

And in your activity you must do something like this :

```
MusicAdaper adaper = new MusicAdaper(this, new ArrayList<Music>(), new onLongItemClickLLsitener() {
            @Override
            public void onLonClick(View view) {
                // do something here
            }
        });
```

Comment: In loader activity it is throwing an error:` `error:(51, 24) error: constructor MusicAdapter in class MusicAdapter cannot be applied to given types;
required: Context,List<Music>,onLongItemClickLLsitener
found: LoaderActivity,ArrayList<Music>
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length`

Comment: Remember to modify the constructor as well as the adapter to recevide , 1. a context, 2. a List<Music>, 3. onLongItemClickLLsitener

Comment: I think there is still some short mistake as the activity fails to load, shall I push it on git?

Comment: If you give me the repo i can take a look at it for you